# User Star Rating is Not working in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

My HTMLCode:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="star-rating">
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="1"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="2"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="3"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="4"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5"></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="whatever1" class="rating-value" value="2.56">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.star-rating { line-height:32px; font-size:1.25em; } .star-rating .fa-star{color: yellow;} JS:
```

JS Code :

```
<script>
  var $star_rating = $('.star-rating .fa');

  var SetRatingStar = function () {
    return $star_rating.each(function () {
      if (parseInt($star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val()) >= parseInt($(this).data('rating'))) {
        return $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
      } else {
        return $(this).removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
      }
    });
  };

  $star_rating.on('click', function () {
    $star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val($(this).data('rating'));
    return SetRatingStar();
  });

  SetRatingStar();
  $(document).ready(function () {

  });
</script>
```

I want to show user rating in my application.Only Star is shown while using this code.When the user click the star to rate
its not working.What was Wrong here.I am currently tried this code in angular 5.How to achieve this?

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz.com and is there any reason to use jqurey?

Comment: Your code is working standalone. May be angular is causing some issue . add your code in stackblitz.com as the above comment suggested to so that we can try and help you.

Comment: I will try.thanks for response

Comment: have you tried importing the script as a library in your component?

Comment: I add the script link in index.html file

Comment: You should use a controlValueAccessor for that so you can integrate it as part of a form :) brilliant article here https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/